# Itemreader in Spring Batch: Reading 2 different files using single ItemReader

Tags: spring-batch

is it possible to read 2 different files using spring batch Itemreader (in the Single reader) and compare the attributes(like ID column) present in these 2 files.Based on these comparison of IDs using Itemprocessor and the record will be written using Itemwriter in new file

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to read 2 different files using spring batch Itemreader (in the Single reader)

No, that's not possible. You would need to use two steps, each step having its own reader for a specific file.

For your use case, one technique is to stage data in temporary tables (could be in-memory) and join/compare/filter data on these tables before writing it.

Hope this helps.